# Importing a python module by path

Tags: python, import, module, path

I have the following mis-fortunate situation:

Three directories (`A`, `B` and `C`) contain a python module `M` with a function `F`. (Those directories are not packages and it is impossible to change anything about the situation.)

I am looking for a way to import them separately to access their functionalities. How do I need to import those modules to access `F` somewhat like this:

```
A.F()
B.F()
C.F()
```

Comment: user from a.M import F as A_F

Comment: I'm curious about how you got into this f0rked up situation, why can't you solve it the 'proper' way and now have to hack something together?

Comment: @wim The f0rked up situation is a dependency and you do not want to change things in a dependency or you will end up messing up the interface which leads to god knows what... This is why I am looking for a 'proper' way at least on my side of the interface.

Comment: Duplicate of [How to import a module given the full path?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/67631/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to exec things into a new locals dictionary.  You can only get to the files you mention as files, not as modules, then stuff them into a moduletype.

```
from types import ModuleType

with open("A/M.py") as a:
    A = ModuleType('A')
    exec a.read() in A.__dict__

with open("B/M.py") as b:
    B = ModuleType('B')
    exec b.read() in B.__dict__

with open("C/M.py") as c:
    C = ModuleType('C')
    exec c.read() in C.__dict__
```

Then access them like B.F() as you wanted.  The only problem is the module metadata isn't set up correctly, so it will appear as a builtin. You can even then do:

```
import sys
sys.modules['A'] = A
sys.modules['B'] = B
sys.modules['C'] = C
```

and they will be importable like `import A` from other parts of your application.

Comment: Added the sys.modules problem as an advantage to this method by explicitly setting the constructed modules in you can reimport.

Answer (score 4):

This will work, but it seems a bit inelegant...

```
import sys

sys.path.append("A")
import M as A

sys.path.pop()
del sys.modules['M']

sys.path.append("B")
import M as B

and so on...
```

Comment: IMO this is the way to go you just have to fix the fact that `pre_path` point always to `sys.path` so changing `sys.path` will change `pre_path`. What you should do is each time `pop()` from `sys.path` after you finish importing.

Comment: Somehow the module `M` in `B` is not loaded with `import M as B` if previously `import M as A` was imported. If I call `F` of `B` with `B.F()` actually the function `F` in `A` is called.

Comment: ahh and you have also to delete `sys.modules['M']` after importing it, because the next time you try to import the other module `M` the import will be skipped because it's already in `sys.modules`.

Comment: Probably it's still in sys.modules as 'M'

Answer (score 1):

put an `__init__.py` in each A/ B/ and C/. The content of this file is

```
from M import F
```

Than the following code should work:

```
import A, B, C
A.F()
B.F()
C.F()
```

The `__init__.py` declares the directory as a package, and the statements in this file are executed when you import the package.

Comment: Thx for the reply, but as I said, I cannot change anything about how the directories look like. So no `__init__.py` can be added to make it a package.

Answer (score -2):

use import as like

```
from A.M import F as A_F
```

Comment: But then the `sys.path` would have to be set each time I import a module. Could you elaborate on that part?

Comment: @Woltan sorry for my thoughtless you should add your directory to syspath use sys.path.append like the answer from rocksportrocker